# Polynomial approximation on the closed unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, banach-spaces

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and let $A$ be the Banach algebra of functions that are analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with the uniform norm. I want to show that polynomials of the form $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}z^{k}$ are dense in this algebra.

This is covered by Mergelyan's theorem, which is proved in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, but I am wondering if there is a short proof when the hypotheses are simplified to the unit disk. I don't believe it is true that if $f\in A$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ on $\mathbb{D}$, then the equality also holds on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: Take the averages of $P_n$ (in other words if $P_n=\sum_{k\le n}a_kz^k, Q_n=(P_0+..P_n)/(n+1)$ and use Feijer theorem to show that $Q_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the closed unit disc

Comment: @Conrad how do I use Fejer’s theorem for functions that are defined on a disk and not on a circle?

Comment: Are you essentially saying to use the Banach space isomorphism between $A$ and a certain closed subspace of continuous functions on the circle?

Comment: I would consider something simpler. Given $f \in A$, look at its dilation $f_r(z) = f(rz)$ for $r < 1$. Then $f_r \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ as $r\rightarrow 1$. The power series expansion $f_r(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k r^k z^k$ is valid in a slightly larger disk, so $\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k r^k z^k \rightarrow f_r$ uniformly on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: @nowhere I agree that $f_{r}\rightarrow f$ uniformly but I don’t understand why the power series for $f_{r}$ converges uniformly on the entire closed unit disk.

Comment: For $r < 1$, $f(rz)$ is analytic in the open disk $D_r = \{|z| < 1/r\}$ - which has radius strictly greater than $1$. The power series $f_r(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k r^k z^k$ converges absolutely in $D_r$. Since $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact and contained in $D_r$, the convergence is uniform on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.